# Product of Functions Holomorphic in Different Subsets of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be analytic in $C\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ and let $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be analytic in $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}$. Show that $f\cdot g$ is analytic in $C\cap D$.

I know that the product of two functions analytic in the same subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is analytic in that subset, so it seems reasonable to say that the product of functions analytic in different subsets would be analytic wherever $f\left(z\right)$ and $g\left(z\right)$ are both analytic. I’m trying to figure out how to show this rigorously. Or is there a counterexample to this?

Comment: If you know that $f$ is holomorphic on $C$, then it will also be holomorphic on the open subset $C\cap D$, and the same argument holds for $g$, which gives you two holomorphic functions on the same open subset

Comment: @asdq thank you! Makes perfect sense now

Answer (score 1):

Answering this question since I think I’ve figured it out now:

Since $\left(C\cap D\right)\subseteq C$, $f$ is analytic in $C\cap D$. Similarly, $g$ is also analytic in $C\cap D$. Since both functions are analytic in the same subset and the product of functions analytic in the same subset is also analytic in that subset, $f\cdot g$ is analytic in $C\cap D$.